# flexbox - Column contains div rows not working

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

Purpose: a flexbox page with a background image (cover) that may grow in height when the screen shrinks forcing elements to wrap; But it has header bar at the top.

I made the whole screen a column with a background image.
First element in the column: a mock header bar.
Second element is SUPPOSED to be a div - flex-direction: row, but the colored divs inside still behave like it's in a column.

[image]

```
    html, body { box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; width: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: default }

.workspace {
  background: url("../../../assets/Images/WhatIsHunter2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  h1 {
    color: #E0B228;
  }

  h2 {
    color: #2856E0;
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class='workspace' [ngStyle]="{'display': 'flexbox', 'flex-direction': 'column'}">
  <div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100vw', 'height': '60px', 'background-color': 'beige'}">
    This is its own row at the top of the column - a header bar
  </div>
  <div [ngStyle]="{'margin-top': '20px', 'display': 'flexbox', 'flex-direction': 'row', 'justify-content': 'space-evenly'}">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100px', 'height': '100px', 'background-color': 'red'}">
    </div>
    <div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100px', 'height': '100px', 'background-color': 'green'}">
    </div>
    <div [ngStyle]="{'width': '100px', 'height': '100px', 'background-color': 'blue'}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `'display': 'flex'` and not `'display': 'flexbox'` in your ng-style declaration on the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `display: flexbox;` to `display: flex;` and it will work

Comment: Oh!  I should have caught that.  It's this kind of embarrassment that guarantees I will never forget that again.  Thanks so much for your help.
Yogi.